# Retaining co-ordinate values with 6 significant figures when converting shapefile into Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, excel

Using ArcGIS-desktop, I converted a shapefile, into an Excel table through the conversion tool Table to Excel, however my co-ordinates previously were specific to the 1x10-6 (i.e. 9.078627) but in the new Excel spreadsheet they have been converted into whole numbers (i.e. 9).

Is there a method to retain the original specificity of the data points when converting?

Comment: what software are you using? and were your coordinates really that accurate?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: I've managed to sort out my problem by doing the following:
1. Add a field for lat and lon (specify as a double) in the attribute table
2. Click on new field and calculate geometry in the coordinate reference system of the area (for both lat & lon).
3. Used the Table to Excel method to convert.